# Limit the percenatage value between 0% and 100% in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to limit the percentage from 0% to 100%. I can do one of them by using minimum or Max. is there a way to do both min and max?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Use one nested in the other:

```
=MIN(1,MAX(0,A1))
```